# Missing Plugin GWT error in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to run an existing GWT project in Eclipse as a Web Application.  This runs on other people's PCs, and I used a setup document common to us all to install Eclipse and GWT.  I consistently got the error:

Google Error
Not Found
The requested URL /missing-plugin/ was not found on this server.

So far, I have verified that the GWT SDK is installed, and that the Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.5 is installed.  I uninstalled just the Google Plugin, and then everything Google, and reinstalled, with no luck.  at this point, after poking around a lot, all the Google stuff is installed, but the "Run as Web Application" option is completely gone.  I've googled this, but no luck so far.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of GWT 2 (or there about), a new browser plugin is required for developer mode. You can get it here: http://gwt.google.com/samples/MissingPlugin/MissingPlugin.html